# How to get the xml root node containing element with particular value using groovy scripts in soap ui

Tags: groovy, soapui

Suppose my xml response is below:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <GetCitiesByCountryResponse xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
         <GetCitiesByCountryResult><![CDATA[<NewDataSet>
  <Table>
    <Country>British Indian Ocean Territory</Country>
    <City>Diego Garcia</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>India</Country>
    <City>Ahmadabad</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>India</Country>
    <City>Akola</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>India</Country>
    <City>Aurangabad</City>
  </Table>
```

Here I want get the `<Country>` element value from the root node `<Table>` name that contains `<City>` as "Akola" using SoapUi groovy scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder
def testCase = messageExchange.modelItem.testCase
def responseHolder = new XmlHolder(messageExchange.getResponseContentAsXml());
def resultFromServer = responseHolder["//Table/City[text()='Akola']/ancestor::Table[1]/Country/text()"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can try this:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.model.testsuite.TestRunner
def groovyUtils= new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)

def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(XML)

def nodeValue= holder.getNodeValue("//Table/City[text()='Akola']/../Country/text()")
```