# How to assert xml element with particular value using groovy scripts in soapUI

Tags: groovy, soapui, assert

propose my xml is below

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <GetCitiesByCountryResponse xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
         <GetCitiesByCountryResult><![CDATA[<NewDataSet>
<Tables>
  <Table>
    <Country>British Indian Ocean Territory</Country>
    <City>Diego Garcia</City>
  </Table>
</Tables>
<Tables>
  <Table>
    <Country>India</Country>
    <City>Ahmadabad</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>USA</Country>
    <City>Akola</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>India</Country>
    <City>Aurangabad</City>
  </Table>
</Tables>
```

I want so assert that one of the City element is "Ahmadabad". How can i do it using soapUI and groovy

Comment: It's too similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20769846/how-to-get-the-xml-root-node-containing-element-with-particular-value-using-groo

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your xml is in a String like:

```
def xml = '''<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            |    <soap:Body>
            |        <GetCitiesByCountryResponse xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
            |            <GetCitiesByCountryResult><![CDATA[<NewDataSet>
            |                <Tables>
            |                    <Table>
            |                        <Country>British Indian Ocean Territory</Country>
            |                        <City>Diego Garcia</City>
            |                    </Table>
            |                </Tables>
            |                <Tables>
            |                    <Table>
            |                        <Country>India</Country>
            |                        <City>Ahmadabad</City>
            |                    </Table>
            |                    <Table>
            |                        <Country>USA</Country>
            |                        <City>Akola</City>
            |                    </Table>
            |                    <Table>
            |                        <Country>India</Country>
            |                        <City>Aurangabad</City>
            |                    </Table>
            |                </Tables>
            |            </NewDataSet>]]></GetCitiesByCountryResult>
            |        </GetCitiesByCountryResponse>
            |    </soap:Body>
            |</soap:Envelope>'''.stripMargin()
```

Then you can do this to get a list of City names:

```
def cdata = new XmlSlurper().parseText( xml )
                            .Body
                            .GetCitiesByCountryResponse
                            .GetCitiesByCountryResult
                            .text()
def cities = new XmlSlurper().parseText( cdata ).Tables.Table.City*.text()
```

And then you can check your city is there by:

```
assert cities.contains( 'Ahmadabad' )
```